# Exif showing wrong resolution of captured image using camera api in oreo 8.1.0

Tags: android, android-camera, exif, android-8.1-oreo, google-pixel

In Pixel2 XL Android 8.1.0 ,  image captured in portrait mode using camera api is showing wrong resolution whereas image captured in landscape is showing right resolution.

Android Version: 8.1.0
Device tested: Google Pixel2 XL device

Steps to reproduce:
1. Capture image using Custom camera or open camera app available in play store which is using camera api in portrait mode.
2. Open file explorer to see image property.
3. Capture image in landscape mode.
4. Open file explorer to see image property.

Expected result:
In portrait mode it should show resolution as 3036x4048

Actual result:
In portrait mode it is showing resoultion as 4048x3036

NOTE:
This issue is not observed in Android 8.0 (O). Also the resolution info is correct if we capture image using device camera not using camera api.

[image]

Comment: My god.. Why are you calling that a wrong resolution? Its the right resolution! But portrait is landscape. You should only take into account the orientation.

Comment: Further this does not seem a programming problem.

Comment: @greenapps Thanks for the reply. I am passing captured image to third party lib and that lib relies on exif info to read height and width of the image. My requirement is to send image with right exif info I tried to update the exif info by android code but it is not working.

Comment: Why do you suggest that the exif info is not right? Never seen it not right. You should not only consider resolution but also orientation. If that library only looks at resolution than the library is wrong. You could have started your post with that.

Comment: Please show your Android exif manupilating code. Which orientation values do you get?

Comment: @greenapps I have updated my post by adding screen shot where I am getting wrong resolution information.

Comment: Is that a screenshot of some dialog of your app? Or of ES File Explorer? Or what? Why so unclear?

Comment: In that screenshot it may be the wrong resolution according to you but the thumbnail is displayed in portrait mode. So orientation is taken into account.

Comment: Looks like a system bug, and it deserves reporting elsewhere. When you file your ticket, check if it reproduces with camera2 API. As for the programming issue you have, exif manipulation should resolve it.

Comment: @greenapps Sorry for creating doubt. This is the screen shoot from ES Explorer. I copied this image to my laptop and tried using photoshop and getting the wrong resolution there also. My problem is getting wrong exif info.

Comment: @AlexCohn Thanks for reply. I already posted it to Google any they are trying to diagnose the issue.

Comment: `tried using photoshop and getting the wrong resolution there also. My problem is getting wrong exif info.`. No you get the right resolution but wxh reversed. And your problem is that you do not take into account orientation. Which ES File Explorer does.

Comment: I am not sure that by contract the JPEG received from ImageReader must contain EXIF headers. Even if it does, the orientation is not set automagically: the API expects you to specify this orientation in [capture request](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#JPEG_ORIENTATION). Please read [this Medium article](https://medium.com/@kenodoggy/solving-image-rotation-on-android-using-camera2-api-7b3ed3518ab6) and especially the conclusions.